# MouseDown, PreviewMouseDown, etc... and COMMAND Binding in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, command, mousedown

I'm trying to understand this concept and it's eluding me.

What is the general concept behind this?  I know it's possible, but I'm not totally following how to do this based on my research/own test projects.

I want to avoid code behind at all costs in my View.  I want to decouple events such as "PreviewMouseDown" from the View and have them trigger a Command in the ViewModel.

Can anyone give me some basic guidance on how to accomplish this?

Summary:

View (PreviewMouseDown) -> Calls Command in ViewModel (MyPreviewMouseDownCommand)

Thank you

Comment: Codebehind is not a dreadful sin. Some task are solved very easy with codebehind. The main idea of MVVM pattern is not allowing VM to know much about View. And View must no nothing about model. If you codebehind works with the view only - it's ok. Even if it depends on VM - it still ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about [Commanding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) and [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx). But I'll encourage you to better use a framework that provides you the plumbing. If you want View first strategy you can you go with MVVM Light as [Reed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12270159/744484) suggested. But, if you want ViewModel first approach (which I **personally** found to be more simple to understand) then I'll suggest you to use [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/).

Anyway, you'll end up using Event to Command or the Interactivity Library (from the Blend SDK) if you want to go code-behind clean.

Answer (score 15):

At risk of being downvoted I don't think this is the worst thing in the world

```cs
public void PreviewMouseDown(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel= (MyViewModel)DataContext;
    if (viewModel.MyCommand.CanExecute(null))
        viewModel.MyCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is typically handled via some form of [Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) or [(Blend) Behavior](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2009/03/23/an-introduction-to-behaviors-triggers-and-actions.aspx).

For example, MVVM Light includes an [EventToCommand Behavior](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx) which allows you to route any event to an `ICommand` in XAML, with no code behind added.

Comment: Another option is using the Blend SDK's EventTrigger coupled with InvokeCommandAction. The downside to this versus EventToCommand is that InvokeCommandAction doesn't allow for passing of the event args to the command as a parameter.